# How to find number of occurrences that don't have (3) instances within defined time frame period (6 weeks)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to find all patients who have not had 3 visits within a 6 week period during a rolling year. 
 I’ll start from a temp table that has all results for 1 year period, like this:

```
TempTable1  
PatientName       VisitDate 
Steve             11/1/2016
Steve             11/2/2016
Steve             11/3/2016
Pete              11/1/2016
Pete              11/2/2016
Dave                  2/3/2016   
Dave              11/2/2016
Dave              2/2/2016
```

But I still need to

```
Select 
        PatientName
       ,/*most recent VisitDate*/
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By PatientName ORDER BY VisitDate desc) AS RowNumber
FROM TempTable1
   Where /*PatientName has <3 visits within any rolling 6 week period */
```

The result should be "Pete" and "Dave" since both do not have three visits within six week period. Steve does 3 visits within 6 weeks.

I could not find any good examples where they looked for more than once instance within a time frame. Thank you many times in advance.  I'll be sure to leave great rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person got three visits within six weeks, when we find a visit where the previous visit and the following visit are no more than six weeks apart. We can use `LAG` and `LEAD` to find the previous and the following visits to a visit.

```
select patientname
from (select distinct patientname from temp) patients
where patientname not in
(
  select patientname
  from
  (
    select
      patientname, 
      lag(visitdate) over (partition by patientname order by visitdate) as visit1,
      lead(visitdate) over (partition by patientname order by visitdate) as visit3
    from temp
  ) visits
  where datediff(day, visit1, visit3) <= 42 -- 42 days = 6 weeks
);
```

Comment: Thank you Thorsten- I'm not super advanced at this and am amazed at the approach.  Can you help me understand if I'm reading this query correctly? I'm looking for instances where patient did "not" have three ( or more) visits within 6 weeks.  Would this query exclude (not return) patients that had two visits within the 6 week period?  What's the part of this query that ensures a total of 3 visits within the 6 week period?  Does lag and lead mean that you have to have a third visit in between? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have `visitdate` of the record itself, `lag(visitdate)` of the previous record and `lead(visitdate)` of the following record. So the subquery finds all instances where three visits lay within six weeks. The outer query finds all patients not in this list. Two visits only within six weeks would not be found by the subquery and hence not prevent a patient from being selected in the main query.

Answer (score 2):

This is challenging.  I think that `cross apply` might be the simplest method to implement:

```
select t.*, tt.numvisits
from temptable1 t cross apply
     (select count(*) as numvisits
      from temptable t2
      where t2.patientname = t.patientname and
            t2.visitdate >= t.visitdate and
            t2.visitdate < dateadd(week, 6, t.visitdate)
     ) tt;
```

Then, if you want to find the people who don't have three visits:

```
select t.patientname
from temptable1 t cross apply
     (select count(*) as numvisits
      from temptable t2
      where t2.patientname = t.patientname and
            t2.visitdate >= t.visitdate and
            t2.visitdate < dateadd(week, 6, t.visitdate)
     ) tt;
group by t.patientname
having max(numvisits) < 3;
```

Note that the `cross apply` can take advantage of an index on `temptable(patientdate, visitdate)`.  If your data is not too big, then performance may even be reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution. I think this one is great, but I ultimately implemented the other solution.  Nothing wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this from the other side. We'll check if minimum visit date within 3 preceding visits (current included) is within 6 weeks from current visit date.

```
with dat as (
  -- sample data
  select *
  from (
    values 
     ('Steve',cast('11/1/2016' as date))
    ,('Steve',cast('11/2/2016' as date))
    ,('Steve',cast('11/3/2016' as date))
    ,('Pete ',cast('11/1/2016' as date))
    ,('Pete ',cast('11/2/2016' as date))
    ,('Dave ',cast('2/3/2016' as date)) 
    ,('Dave ',cast('11/2/2016' as date))
    ,('Dave ',cast('2/2/2016' as date))
    )t(PatientName, VisitDate) 
), cte as(
 select PatientName
    , md=datediff(week
                  ,min(VisitDate) over(partition by PatientName order by VisitDate 
                                       rows between 2 preceding and current row)
                   ,VisitDate)
    , n = count(*) over(partition by PatientName order by VisitDate 
                      rows between 2 preceding and current row)                                                                      
  from dat
)
select PatientName
from cte
group by PatientName
having max(n)<3 or max(md)>6
```

Comment: I think this one would will work for the example given, but not for my particular application--- because I could have thousands of names with the names and dates are constantly changing and varied. I should have supplied that information. Thank you again! The support means a lot.

Comment: If you mean the values part, it's just to generate some sample data. Use your real table in `cte as ( select ... from dat)` instead of sample `dat`.

Answer (score 1):

This my proposition. Code is simple and is based on the fact 6 weeks=42 days. I hope that I helped

```
   WITH TMP_CTE AS(
    Select 
            PatientName,
        VisitDate,
        LEAD(VisitDate, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY PatientName ORDER BY VisitDate) AS OffsetVisitDate
            DATEDIFF(day, VisitDate, LEAD(VisitDate, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY PatientName ORDER BY VisitDate)) as Difference_in_Days
    FROM TempTable1
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT PatientName AS Patient_who_has_not_3visits
    FROM TMP_CTE WHERE PatientName NOT IN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT PatientName AS Patient_who_has_3visits_within_6week
    FROM TMP_CTE
    WHERE Difference_in_Days>42
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution. I think this one is will work well, but I ultimately implemented the other solution because it was just easier for me to understand.  So appreciate you!